# FB.GetAuthResponse not calling CallBack

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I've been trying to get FB.GetAuthResponse to work in both my test App and the FriendSmash example app with the most recent Facebook sdk for Unity with no luck.

The function never calls the provided callback.  This means I have no way to get the user information of a user who is already connected to the App.

Anyone know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FB.Login("", delegate)`